# Invoke function in parent abstract class from child class in my case

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I have a **abstract** class:

```
public abstract class Parent{

    public void cook(){
        DoSomething(); //call abstract method
    }

    protected abstract void DoSomething();

}
```

I have a concrete class which imiplements the above abstract class:

```
public Child extends Parent{
   private Toy toy;

   public void initToy(){
      toy.setOnPlayListener(new OnPlayListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                //How to call parent class cook() method here?
            }
        });
   }

   @Override
   public void DoSomething(){...}
}
```

I want to call the `cook()` method of `Parent` class **under current Child instance** in the override `onPlay()` function of `OnPlayListener()` in `Child` class. How to do it?

**========Update=======**

Thanks for your answers, now I would like to make it clear, are `Child.super.cook()` & `Child.this.cook()` the same thing ??

Comment: Every Child instance will refer to the same method in its Parent class, so the "under current Child instance" part of your question is unnecessary.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder, do you mean Child.super.cook() & Child.this.cook() are the same ??

Comment: @Mellon No they're completely different. They're equivalent respectively to super.cook() and this.cook(), if called from a method in Child directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the enclosing class instance's super class

```
@Override
public void onPlay() {
    Child.super.cook();
}
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is something what I am looking for.  I want to call it under the current Child instance, probably use Child.this.cook() ???

Comment: @Mellon You said `I want to call the cook() method of Parent class`. If you want to call the `Child` class'` `cook()` method, you need to use `Child.this.cook()` or `cook()` directly.

Comment: `Child.this.super.cook();` & `Child.super.cook();` both are same ?

Comment: @vels4j No, `Child.this.super.cook();` won't compile.

Comment: Please update your answer to the correct one then I will accept it

Comment: I see it but I have updated my post, there is a clear issue still

Comment: @Mellon Sorry I was away. In this case `Child.this.cook()` and `Child.super.cook()` will invoke the same method because you haven't overriden it in the `Child` class.